# Where is my Webforms data being stored?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, connection-string

I am new to .NET technologies. From a few days I have worked with C# .NET and ASP.NET I think I was doing well. Now my question is: my friends asked me about database connections between C# .NET WebForms and a database. Practically, I did not write any code between C# WebForms using a database connection. I did not install any SQL Server yet. So can I develop WebForms without a database connection? And where is my WebForms database is stored? Is it storing data on my computer drives?

Comment: If you use any database control, have a look at your *web.config* file in the `<connectionSettings>` section. If you see any, that one should be used for getting data. Most likely it will be MS SQL Express that comes with Visual Studio installation.

Answer (score 1):

It uses SQL Server Express Edition. You can connect to it via this connection string:

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
            database=YourDatabaseName;
            AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;
            User Instance=true"
```

Microsoft SQL Server Express provides a simple database solution for building applications. SQL Server Express supports the complete SQL Server programming model including T-SQL, stored procedures, views, triggers, SQL Server CLR Integration (SQLCLR), and the XML data type. When you develop an application using SQL Server Express as the data source, the application will be compatible with production servers that run SQL Server.

App_Data is essentially a storage point for file-based data stores (as opposed to a SQL server database store for example). Some simple sites make use of it for content stored as XML for example, typically where hosting charges for a database are expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Database is for permanent data storage. If your application has nothing to store ,there is no need for any database. A .NET web application will work fine without any database.

Moreover you can also store data on a file or XML.